# How to filter out words in a corpus from a constrained vocabulary with gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I am using gensim for topic modeling. I've created a corpus using

```
wordDict = corpora.Dictionary(trimmedTextTokens)

gsCorpus = [wordDict.doc2bow(text) for text in trimmedTextTokens]
```

where trimmedTextTokens are the result of removing stop words. Now I want to filter out the terms from the corpus that are not in a list of a restricted or constructed vocabulary. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your restricted vocabulary list is in a variable named `restrictedVocabularyList` you could do:

```
wordDict = corpora.Dictionary(trimmedTextTokens)

gsCorpus = [wordDict.doc2bow(text) for text in trimmedTextTokens if text in restrictedVocabularyList]
```

Comment: If you found the answer helpful I would appreciate it if you could accept it.